# Understanding Three-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to wrap my head around three-dimensional arrays. I understand that they are arrays of two-dimensional arrays, but the book I'm reading said something that confuses me.

In an exercise for the book I'm reading, it asks me to make a three-dimensional array for a full-color image. It gives a small example saying this:

> If we decide to choose a three-dimensional array, here's how the array might be declared:

```
int[][][] colorImage = new int[numRows][numColumns][3];
```

However, wouldn't it be more effective like this?

```
int[][][] colorImage = new int[3][numRows][numColumns];
```

Where 3 is the rgb values, 0 being red, 1 being green, and 2 being blue. With the latter, each two-dimensional array would be storing the color value of the row and column, right? I just want to make sure I understand how to effectively use a three-dimensional array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's the same. You can use dimensions as you please, as long as it's consistent. There is no performance or memory difference.

Comment: Why do you believe the order makes a difference?

Comment: @Luxspes I don't believe it. I know it.

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, but I was talking to Jake Wilson, not to you

Comment: @Bohemian also.. what do you mean? from what I read, you, as me, believe the order makes no difference... so... what are you tying to say?

Comment: thanks for the responses. I thought the order made a difference because I thought if I had the 3 in front that would mean there were 3 two-dimensional arrays, as opposed to numRows amount of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order doesn't matter, and in fact the former form is more readable:

```
final const int RED = 0;
final const int GREEN = 1;
final const int BLUE = 2;

int[][][] colorImage = new int[numRows][numColumns][3];
//...

int x = getSomeX();
int y = getSomeY();

int redComponent = colorImage[x][y][RED];
int greenComponent = colorImage[x][y][GREEN];
int blueComponent = colorImage[x][y][BLUE];
```

Answer (score 2):

The order shouldn't matter, so one isn't more effective than the other.  The only thing that matters is that whatever accesses colorImage knows which dimension is used for what.  Bit more context on multidimensional arrays [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Multi-dimensional_arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its a good idea to put everything in an 3dimensional array of int.

Your first mistake is the dataytpe:
RGB is a int. 
But R is a byte, G is a byte, B is a byte too.. (`Color.getXXX()` delivers an int, I dont know why because its a byte 0-255)

You need an int because you want to address more than 256 cols&rows. (Thats okay).
But i think that its much better to encapsulate the color information in a extra object. Perhaps a private datastructure like

```
class MyColor {

        public byte r, g, b;    //public for efficient access;
        public int  color;      //public for efficient access;

        public MyColor(final int rgb) {
            this(new Color(rgb));
        }

        public MyColor(final Color c) {
            this((byte) c.getRed(), (byte) c.getGreen(), (byte) c.getBlue(), c.getRGB());
        }

        public MyColor(final byte red, final byte green, final byte blue, final int c) {
            this.r = red;
            this.g = green;
            this.b = blue;
            this.color = c;
        }
    }
```

and put this in an 2dim array of `MyColor[numRows][numColumns]`

But if you make the class MyColor public to your whole app - i would change the design of the class to be more secure.