# Java multidimensional array

Tags: java

I have a number of two dimensional arrays of different sizes, such as:

```
size of A1:  10 * 8
size of A2:  10 * 10
size of A3:  10 * 12
```

Is there any way I can put them into one structure to get a three dimensional object?

Comment: `int[][][]` [3dArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623990/understanding-three-dimensional-arrays). Altough, your question lacks of any effort on trying to understand this by yourself.

Comment: so you put it in 3d array and what next? it is not clear what your goal is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
YourType[][][] array3d = new YourType[3][][];
array3d[0] = A1;
array3d[1] = A1;
array3d[2] = A1;
```